# Spring @ActiveProfiles no longer supports comma separated profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

We're currently in the process of updating to Spring Boot 2.4.8 (Spring 5.3.8) and our integration tests are failing.

After some long debugging I found out that our @ActiveProfiles annotation was no longer working for two profiles. We defined it as followed:

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev,postgres")
```

However with the new Spring Boot version this no longer loads our application-dev.yml and application-postgres.yml files. If I define it as the following, it works again:

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = {"dev", "postgres"})
```

Is this a known change? because I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a known change and very annoying.

It came with Spring Boot 2.3 but I can't say the exact version.

On the other hand the value of `ActiveProfiles` was always a array so that the supported a comma separated value was a mistake.